# The return of the messy chemist

Tags: knowledge, pattern, visual, chemistry

My Chemistry teacher is [at it again](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/111810/60644). Today, I cautiously approached his office and stopped in the doorway instead of walking right in - and it's a good job I did. There he was again - bent over on the carpet, arranging his Periodic Table element flashcards in some new and completely unscientific manner, taking up almost the entire floor.

Under his breath, he muttered, "Gargh, I haven't left enough room at the top..." and in his hands he held two flashcards whose faces I couldn't quite see. At this point he became suddenly aware of my presence, stood up abruptly, and concealed these two flashcards behind his back.

I opened my mouth to speak but he beat me to it. "You have another question about the classwork, don't you?" He smiled. "Tell you what - you can ask your question, but only if you can first tell me which two elements I am holding in my hand..."

> **TASK: Considering the arrangement of flashcards below, which two elements are missing from the pattern? Where should they both be placed in relation to the other cards on the floor?**

[image: Flashcard arrangement]

Comment: Did you create this puzzle?

Comment: Fun fact (ROT13):  Va Pnanqn, gurer'f bayl bar cebivapr be greevgbel (bhg bs guvegrra) jubfr cbfgny nooerivngvba vf funerq jvgu na ryrzrag.  So that might not make for a good puzzle.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Yes I did, and the one linked in the preamble. Each flashcard is made of three cells in MS Excel, which I then snipped and overlaid in their corresponding positions over the relevant map (which I deleted before posting here). Two long lists had to be consulted to make sure I caught them all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your teacher is holding cards for the elements

> PA and HS! (Protactinium and Hassium)

Reasoning:  The cards are arranged in the order of the

> British Postal Codes, as shown here:
>  [image: map]

> Near the top of the map we see spaces for PA and HS, where there wasn't quite enough room on the original image.

Comment: Aw, looks like you beat me to it while I was making the image.

Comment: Well spotted :) Checkmark awarded on timestamp grounds since both answers are correct and include a diagram - couldn't really ask for much more!

Answer (score 10):

It seems like the two missing elements are

> Hassium (Hs) and Protactinium (Pa)...

or rather,

> the Outer Hebrides and Paisley!
>
>  These are the postal codes of the UK, arranged as shown in the following image:
>
>  [image: UK map with corresponding regions highlighted]