# A Serious Tale of Two Countries

Tags: knowledge, visual, letters

The seven regions formed by the intersecting ellipses are each home to exactly one of the seven tiles.

Can you place the tiles so that those in each ellipse can be rearranged to solve the corresponding clue?

[image: Blank Venn diagram to be solved]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to get exactly one tile in each of the seven internal regions, the Venn diagram should be resolved as follows:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

This way:

> The '**A:Country**' category contains all the segments required to spell the name of the Asian country **CA-MB-OD-IA**;
>
>  The '**B:Country**' category contains all the segments required to spell the name of the South American country **CO-LO-MB-IA**;
>
>  The '**C:Grave**' category contains all the segments required to spell the word **CA-TA-CO-MB**, a synonym of 'grave'.
>
>  (NB The choice of which country to place in which of the two country circles is arbitrary - I went with alphabetical order...)

Comment: May I ask what image editing software you use? Like in general? I would like to make some visual puzzles, but don't know how...

Comment: @smlee Nothing too fancy :) Just the Windows basics really - I use **MS Paint** predominantly for editing images like in this answer, and the **Windows Snipping Tool** for taking selective screenshots. When I make my own puzzles I tend to create most things - especially grids (e.g. for crosswords) in **MS Excel**. See [this recent 'making of' post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/116468/60644) for a few shots of the intermediate stages of my creative process in Excel.

Comment: May I ask how you made the image in [this post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116428/the-return-of-the-messy-chemist)? Thanks!

Comment: @smlee Sure - all in MS Excel; each element symbol card is two rows with a border, ratio top:bottom row 3:4 (ditto for font sizes). Then I hid the Excel gridlines in the View tab, used the Windows Snipping Tool to carefully cut around each one to make it a movable image, and manually positioned them all over a map from the web as a guide (removing the map once done). Lots of snipping and positioning, really, then one big snip to save the whole image :)

Comment: Solved within 1 hour, Stiv is actually hacking!!!